# Python: How to get the number range in order

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, graph

Trying to plot a number graph but the number range on x-axis is not ordered.

Code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 def plot_sam_img(self):

            fig = plt.figure()
            plt.xlabel('Range')
            plt.ylabel('Total')

            df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Range':self.value_counts().index, 'Total':self.value_counts().values})

            try:
                df1_cut = df1.groupby(pd.cut(df1["Range"], [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,df1['Range'].max()])).sum()
            except:    
                df1_cut = df1.groupby(pd.cut(df1["Range"], list(xrange(0, df1['Range'].max()+1)))).sum()

            objects = df1_cut['Total'].index
            y_pos = np.arange(len(df1_cut['Total'].index))
            plt.bar(df1_cut['Total'].index.values, df1_cut['Total'].values)
```

Actual O/P:

On x-axis: `[0,1] [1,2] [10,11] [11,12] [2,3] [3,4] [4,5]......`

Expected O/P:

On x-axis: `[00] [01] [02] [03] [04]......[010] [011]`

This way I think the order issue could be sorted out. Please correct if my understanding is wrong here. Thanks

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete. Would you be able to post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?